# HTML button calling server side event

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have an html button:

```
<button runat="server" onserverclick="myBtn_Click()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top" >Top</button>
```

In my code-Behind I have:

```
 protected void myBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindListView();
    }
```

When I run the code I get this error:

"No overload for method 'myBtn_Click' takes 0 arguments"

Please help.

Comment: You don't give any parameters in your HTML, when you call the function, but it requires two.

Comment: OnServerClick should only be the name of the function you are calling. `onServerClick="myBtn_Click"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want the () for the function.

In fact, let intel-sense BOTH create, and/or select the event for you.

So, say this in the markup, note how when I hit "=", then you get/see intel-sense to select a existing event stub, or in most cases create a new stub.

eg this:

[image]